# Failed to download OpenAPI error with Kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm learning Kubernetes and I've just installed minikube on my mac.

I have a docker image that I'd like to deploy. I created a deployment yaml file which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarqube
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: docker-sonarqube-developer:latest
          args:
            - -Dsonar.web.context=/
          name: sonarqube
          env:
            - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME
              value: sonarqube
            - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
              value: sonarqube
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              name: sonarqube
```

I am trying to deploy my docker image on minikube with the following command:

```sh
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

But I'm getting an error and I'm not sure what's going on.

```sh
W0628 09:18:45.550812   64359 factory_object_mapping.go:423] Failed to download OpenAPI (the server could not find the requested resource), falling back to swagger
error: error validating "k8s/deployment.yaml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Minikube is running and I can access the dashboard.

```
❯ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
minikube   Ready     master    17h       v1.15.0
```

The docker image is available locally

```
❯ docker ps -a                                                                     
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED      
6fcfdad92d16        docker-sonarqube-developer   "./bin/run.sh"      16 hours
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `docker-sonarqube-developer` image does not exist on dockerhub. if its a private registry -the image should be profixed with its name

Comment: It's a local image on my machine

Comment: It seems that you have incompatible versions for kubectl and the kubernetes cluster. Can you paste the output of `kubectl version`?

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.2", GitCommit:"bdaeafa71f6c7c04636251031f93464384d54963", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-24T19:48:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:32:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Can you do `eval $(minikube docker-env`?

Answer (score 1):

First Check the kubectl version

Check whether the Minor for both client and server version are same

$Kubectl version

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.20.2",

> Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0",

If not,then follow the below steps-

> $curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl

> $chmod +x ./kubectl

> $sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Now check the version again

$kubectl version

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2",

> Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0",

$kubectl create -f deployment.yaml